# my buildozer apk crash on android virtual device

Tags: android, python, apk, kivy, buildozer

I try to compile very simple apps (like HelloWorld stuff) written with python kivy..

I try tu run this apps on different android virtual devices (API 23, 21, 20), all emulating ARM architecture..

each time, i have the same error :

```
11-15 17:19:09.304   246   819 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.test.meetingcostskv/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity (has extras)} from uid 10007 on display 0
11-15 17:19:09.639   246   266 W art     : Long monitor contention event with owner method=int com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(android.app.IApplicationThread, int, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String, android.service.voice.IVoiceInteractionSession, com.android.internal.app.IVoiceInteractor, android.os.IBinder, java.lang.String, int, int, android.app.ProfilerInfo, android.app.IActivityManager$WaitResult, android.content.res.Configuration, android.os.Bundle, boolean, int, android.app.IActivityContainer, com.android.server.am.TaskRecord) from ActivityStackSupervisor.java:946 waiters=0 for 321ms
11-15 17:19:09.679   665   665 I Choreographer: Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-15 17:19:10.084  1292  1292 I art     : Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-15 17:19:10.084  1292  1292 I art     : Late-enabling JIT
11-15 17:19:10.127   246   821 I ActivityManager: Start proc 1292:org.test.meetingcostskv:python/u0a55 for activity org.test.meetingcostskv/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity
11-15 17:19:10.136   665   665 I Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-15 17:19:10.142   246   265 W art     : Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityPaused(android.os.IBinder) from ActivityManagerService.java:6439 waiters=1 for 218ms
11-15 17:19:10.201  1292  1292 I art     : JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
11-15 17:19:11.163   246   819 W art     : Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(long) from WindowAnimator.java:121 waiters=0 for 209ms
11-15 17:19:11.632   246   820 W MountService: No primary storage defined yet; hacking together a stub
11-15 17:19:11.636  1292  1292 W ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
11-15 17:19:11.642   823   823 I Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-15 17:19:11.645  1292  1292 V python  : metadata fullscreen is0
11-15 17:19:11.802   665   665 I Choreographer: Skipped 141 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-15 17:19:11.809  1292  1292 I SDLSurface: Surface will NOT be transparent
11-15 17:19:12.011  1292  1306 V Python  : Extracting private assets.
11-15 17:19:12.065  1292  1306 I python  : extracting libpymodules.so
11-15 17:19:12.514  1292  1292 I Choreographer: Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-15 17:19:12.527  1292  1307 I SDLSurface: Choose egl configuration
11-15 17:19:12.527  1292  1307 I SDLSurface: Try to use graphics config R8G8B8A8S8
11-15 17:19:12.530  1292  1307 I SDLSurface: Try to use graphics config R5G6B5S8
11-15 17:19:12.530  1292  1307 E SDLSurface: Unable to find a correct surface for this device !
11-15 17:19:12.608  1292  1307 I art     : System.exit called, status: 0
11-15 17:19:12.609  1292  1307 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
11-15 17:19:12.661   246   260 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{64660ca u0 org.test.meetingcostskv/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}
11-15 17:19:12.661   246   260 W WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{c74d58 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{64660ca u0 org.test.meetingcostskv/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}
11-15 17:19:12.683   246   333 I ActivityManager: Process org.test.meetingcostskv:python (pid 1292) has died
11-15 17:19:12.685   246   333 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{8290a28 u0 org.test.meetingcostskv/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity t9}: app died, no saved state
11-15 17:19:12.774   246   482 W WindowManager: Failed looking up window
11-15 17:19:12.774   246   482 W WindowManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@3b0f23b does not exist
11-15 17:19:12.774   246   482 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8723)
11-15 17:19:12.774   246   482 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8714)
11-15 17:19:12.774   246   482 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1209)
11-15 17:19:12.774   246   482 W WindowManager:     at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:558)
11-15 17:19:12.774   246   482 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: null
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager: Failed looking up window
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@80d8dc3 does not exist
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8723)
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8714)
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2697)
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.java:187)
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3099)
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5606)
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3409)
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
11-15 17:19:12.834   246   274 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
11-15 17:19:12.989   823   823 W art     : Long monitor contention event with owner method=boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long) from MessageQueue.java:541 waiters=0 for 490ms
11-15 17:19:13.254   246   744 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@bd1bf96 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@acec9b
11-15 17:19:15.355   665   665 I Choreographer: Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-15 17:19:15.785   823   823 I Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I also tried to compile with different android sdk, but buildozer (22, 23) crash...

Comment: My buildozer APK won't even install on AVD, does your at least install?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791960/the-apk-failed-to-install-error-could-not-parse-error-string?noredirect=1#comment90548862_51791960