# The Apk failed to install. Error: Could not pass error string

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Android studio virtual device keeps displaying the below error each time i tried to install app

"The Apk failed to install.
Error: Could not pass error string"

how do I fix this please

I have installed Android Studio on my computer, including all the necessary SDK files. After setting up the virtual device, I proceeded to launch it. However, when I attempted to install the app's APK file by dragging it onto the emulator, I encountered an error message below.

"The Apk failed to install.
Error: Could not pass error string"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The APK failed to install. Error: Could not parse error string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791960/the-apk-failed-to-install-error-could-not-parse-error-string)